# How can I backup unused Evernote tags?

Tags: tags, export, backup, evernote

I use a GTD-based system in Evernote, in which each project has a tag. Some of my projects are inactive, and have no 'next action' - i.e the tag has no notes attached. I accidentally clicked `Delete unused Account tags` last night, and none of my backups have the lost data; I am a very sad bunny.

How can I backup these unused tags in future? I'd prefer an ENEX, but am happy with e.g. a plain-text list of names.

I was using Evernote's 'export' menu-option, but it - it turns out - only exports notes and their tags, not unused tags. I've tried ENScript.exe (`ENScript exportNotes /q any:`) and that does the same: notes & their tags, but no other tags. The only thing left for me to try is installing an SDK and 'rolling my own' call to NoteStore.listTags - which I can't be certain will work, given the previous two results.

Is there a way to export unused tags from Evernote? Can the API do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, through the API.  Use the `listTags` method to get all the tags in your Evernote account, this will list tags that are "attached" to a note and tags that are not "attached" to a note.  You can then compare this to notes that are "attached" to notes by calling `listTagsByNotebook` on every notebook (you can get a list of all the notebooks by calling the `listNotebooks`method).  Evernote's Cloud API is different that their local scripting APIs (i.e AppleScript and VBScript)

`listTags` documentation

`listNotebooks` documentation

`listTagsByNotebook` documentation

Example below is in Python:

```py
 from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
 #setup Evernote Client
 client=EvernoteClient(token="S=s432:U=489be66:E=1545a0ad962:C=14d0259ad08:P=1cd:A=en-devtoken:V=2:H=e3e3c9ea30c6879c54918794fad333ae", sandbox=False)
 #get note store object to call listTags, listTagsByNotebook, and listNotebooks on
 noteStore=client.get_note_store()

 tags=noteStore.listTags() #get list of all tags
 allTags = [tag.name for tag in tags] #put all the names of the tags in a list

 #get a list of all notebooks
 notebooks = noteStore.listNotebooks()
 #get all tags for each notebook and store them in a list
 attachedTags = []
 for notebook in notebooks:
    notebookTagList = noteStore.listTagsByNotebook(notebook.guid)
    notebookTagNames = [tag.name for tag in notebookTagList]
    attachedTags+=notebookTagNames

 #compare lists and print "unattached" tags
 print("\nThe following is a list of \"unattached\" tag names in your Evernote account:")
 for tag in allTags:
    if tag not in attachedTags:
        print("  *%s"%tag)
 print("")
```

You can get a developer token for your production account (Evernote has a sandbox for developers too) here: https://www.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action

Evernote SDKs are on Github: https://github.com/evernote

Documentation is at: https://dev.evernote.com

API reference: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference